# Generating a bill

Tags: java

I am having a problem. In the last switch statement when i press 4 that is to return to main menu. All the values that is entered for 1,2,3 gets reset. What should i do so that these values doesn't get reset. 
package Assignment;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menuSel;
        Boolean done = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 78; i++) {
            System.out.print("=");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\t\t FEDERATION UNIVERSITY PHONE BILL COMPARISON SYSTEM");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Developed by Abhitesh Jindal, Student ID 30334858 for ITECH1000 Semester 1 2017");
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 78; i++) {
            System.out.print("=");
        }
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("\nMAIN MENU");
            System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu: "
                    + "\n\t 1. Enter Usage Details \n\t " + "2. Display Cost Under Plan A \n\t "
                    + "3. Display Cost Under Plan B \n\t " + "4. Clear Usage Details \n\t "
                    + "5. Exit System");
            System.out.println("Enter selection:");
            menuSel = s.nextInt();
            switch (menuSel) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print(" Enter Usage Details ");
                submenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Display Cost Under Plan A");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Display Cost Under Plan B");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Clear Usage Details");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Exit System");
                done = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Value must be between 1 and 5. Please try again:");
                break;
            }
        }
        s.close();
    }

    static void submenu() {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        Boolean done1 = false;
        int numCalls = 0;
        int SMS = 0;
        int callLength = 0;
        int totalCallSeconds = 0;
        while (!done1) {
            System.out.println("\nENTER USAGE DETAILS MENU: " + "\n1. Phone Call" + "\n2. SMS"
                    + "\n3. Data Usage" + "\n4. Return to main menu");
            System.out.println("Enter Selection:");
            int subMenu = a.nextInt();
            switch (subMenu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter Length of Call in Seconds:  ");
                ++numCalls;
                System.out.println("Total Call" + numCalls);
                callLength = a.nextInt();
                totalCallSeconds = totalCallSeconds + callLength;
                System.out.println("Total Seconds" + totalCallSeconds);
                if (callLength < 1) {
                    System.out.println("Value must be positive.Please Enter value again");
                    callLength = a.nextInt();
                    totalCallSeconds = totalCallSeconds + callLength;
                    System.out.println("Total Seconds" + totalCallSeconds);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                ++SMS;
                System.out.print("Total number of SMS= " + SMS);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter amount of Data used:");
                int DataUsed = a.nextInt();
                if (DataUsed < 1) {
                    System.out.println("Value must be positive");
                    System.out.println("Enter Value again");
                    DataUsed = a.nextInt();
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Return to mainu menu");
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
                break;
            }
        }
        a.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you store "usage details"?

Comment: Wrap the properties up in a plain old java object (POJO) and return them to the caller. If you need to, allow the method accept an object carrying previous values to it, so you can update them

Comment: @MadProgrammer: He's not at the POJO stage yet, but rather at the "everything is static" stage. But I don't see any static fields, which I'm guessing he needs.

Comment: i am not sure how to do it. i am very new to this thing. can you please tell me. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I think you should use static fields.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels For the love of sanity, let's not encourage `static` ... a `Map` if all else fails :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer buddy i am pretty new to this. Please tell me how to store the usage details. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user7790438 how. can you please tell me.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Lord knows I'm the last to encourage static fields, but then again when the student is at the crawling stage, sometimes the best we can do is get down with them on our hands and knees.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels We could help them to start learning to walk, maybe use instance fields instead 

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Now I know where the "Mad" epithet comes from. I say, "have at it Don Quixote". ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just like to see the world burn :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could solve this problem, each with their own pros and cons.

You're working in, what's known as, a Object Oriented Programming Language (OOP), this has distinct characteristics and best practices associated with it.

In OOP, the data and the functionality to manipulate/manage that data are "encapsulated" into a "object".  This solution is going to stretch that concept a little, but is basically the same idea.

Rather than operating within the `static` context of the `main` method, this solution is going to create an instance of the `Assign3` and allow the program to operate within its context instead (lots of big words, don't stress just yet).

What this means is, we can define "instance fields", these hold the values/properties of the object and can be shared with the other methods of the object, within the same instance or copy.

So, the first thing I'm going to do, is move the method variables and make them instance fields/variables instead...

```
public class Assign3 {

    int numCalls = 0;
    int SMS = 0;
    int callLength = 0;
    int totalCallSeconds = 0;
```

This makes them available to the whole class

Next, I'm going to move the contents of the `main` method into an instance method of `Assign3` so I can access it from an instance of the class.

```
public void mainMenu() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menuSel;
    Boolean done = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 78; i++) {
        System.out.print("=");
    }
    System.out.println("\n\t\t FEDERATION UNIVERSITY PHONE BILL COMPARISON SYSTEM");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Developed by Abhitesh Jindal, Student ID 30334858 for ITECH1000 Semester 1 2017");
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 78; i++) {
        System.out.print("=");
    }
    while (!done) {
        System.out.println("\nMAIN MENU");
        System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu: "
                + "\n\t 1. Enter Usage Details \n\t " + "2. Display Cost Under Plan A \n\t "
                + "3. Display Cost Under Plan B \n\t " + "4. Clear Usage Details \n\t "
                + "5. Exit System");
        System.out.println("Enter selection:");
        menuSel = s.nextInt();
        switch (menuSel) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print(" Enter Usage Details ");
                submenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Display Cost Under Plan A");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Display Cost Under Plan B");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Clear Usage Details");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Exit System");
                done = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Value must be between 1 and 5. Please try again:");
                break;
        }
    }
    s.close();
}
```

Then, in the `main` method, I'm going to create a new instance of the class and call it's `mainMenu` method to get the ball rolling...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assign3 assign3 = new Assign3();
    assign3.mainMenu();
}
```

While this might seem confusing, this is actually very simple OOP principles. I highly encourage you to have a look at the [Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) trail for more information

Comment: Tilting at windmills, I see

Comment: Covering my ... bases :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer still the same problem. when i press return to menu. it's not storing the values.

Comment: @AbhiteshJindal Then you're probably not removing the local variables from the submenu method